# How to fix this common error of numpy.ndarray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

'''I am working upon a project of analyzing and predicting information about a cricket dataset.I came across a error of numpy.ndarrary object not callable.How should i fix this error'''

```
team1='MI'
team2='CSK'
toss_winner='CSK'
input=[dicVal[team1],dicVal[team2],'15',dicVal[toss_winner],'12','1']
input = np.array(input).reshape((1, -1))
output=model.predict(input)
print(list(dicVal.keys())[list(dicVal.values()).index(output)])
#This code works fine as there is direct initialization of team1 and team2


team1=input("Enter team-1 :")   #<--numpy.ndarrary object not callable
team2=input("Enter team-2 :")
toss_winner=input("Enter toss winner :")
city=input("Enter the corresponding no for the following cities :")
venue=input("Enter the corresponding no for the following stadiums :")
toss=input("Enter the corresponding no for the following toss decision :")

input=[dicVal[team1],dicVal[team2],venue,dicVal[toss_winner],city,toss]
input = np.array(input).reshape((1, -1))
output=model.predict(input)
print(list(dicVal.keys())[list(dicVal.values()).index(output)])
```

'''here on the first line itself i get an error of numpy.ndarrary object not callable.Please help me get this.'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using an unstable version of numpy. I am using the one which is used by google colab i.e. 1.14.6. You can install it using:

```
pip install numpy==1.14.6
```

You can also check your numpy version. Run a python console/ Write a program and execute the following:

```
import numpy
numpy.__version__
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable called input hides the Python function input.

Comment: Until we get the OP's input, I think makes sense.